# PySpark DataFrame Column Reference: df.col vs. df['col'] vs. F.col('col')?

Tags: dataframe, reference, pyspark

I have a concept I hope you can help to clarify:

What's the difference between the following three ways of referring to a column in PySpark dataframe. I know different situations need different forms, but not sure why.

1. **df.col**: e.g.
   `F.count(df.col)`
2. **df['col']**: e.g.
   `df['col'] == 0`
3. **F.col('col')**: e.g. 
   `df.filter(F.col('col').isNull())`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In most practical applictions, there is *almost* no difference. However, they are implemented by calls to different underlying functions ([source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html)) and thus are not *exactly* the same.

We can illustrate with a small example:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1,'a', 0), (2,'b',None), (None,'c',3)], 
    ['col', '2col', 'third col']
)

df.show()
#+----+----+---------+
#| col|2col|third col|
#+----+----+---------+
#|   1|   a|        0|
#|   2|   b|     null|
#|null|   c|        3|
#+----+----+---------+
```

---

#### 1. `df.col`

This is the least flexible. You can only reference columns that are valid to be accessed using the `.` operator. This rules out column names containing spaces or special characters and column names that start with an integer.

This syntax makes a call to `df.__getattr__("col")`.

```python
print(df.__getattr__.__doc__)
#Returns the :class:`Column` denoted by ``name``.
#
#        >>> df.select(df.age).collect()
#        [Row(age=2), Row(age=5)]
#
#        .. versionadded:: 1.3
```

Using the `.` syntax, you can only access the first column of this example dataframe.

```python
>>> df.2col
  File "<ipython-input-39-8e82c2dd5b7c>", line 1
    df.2col
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Under the hood, it checks to see if the column name is contained in `df.columns` and then returns the `pyspark.sql.Column` specified.

#### 2. `df["col"]`

This makes a call to `df.__getitem__`. You have some more flexibility in that you can do everything that `__getattr__` can do, plus you can specify any column name.

```python
df["2col"]
#Column<2col>
```

Once again, under the hood some conditionals are checked and in this case the `pyspark.sql.Column` specified by the input string is returned.

In addition, you can as pass in multiple columns (as a `list` or `tuple`) or column expressions.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df[['col', expr('`third col` IS NULL')]].show()
#+----+-------------------+
#| col|(third col IS NULL)|
#+----+-------------------+
#|   1|              false|
#|   2|               true|
#|null|              false|
#+----+-------------------+
```

Note that in the case of multiple columns, `__getitem__` is just making a call to [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select).

Finally, you can also access columns by index:

```python
df[2]
#Column<third col>
```

#### 3. `pyspark.sql.functions.col`

This is the Spark native way of selecting a column and returns a `expression` (this is the case for all column functions) which selects the column on based on the given name. This is useful shorthand when you need to specify that you want a column and not a string literal.

For example, supposed we wanted to make a new column that would take on the either the value from `"col"` or `"third col"` based on the value of `"2col"`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df.withColumn(
    'new', 
    f.when(df['2col'].isin(['a', 'c']), 'third col').otherwise('col')
).show()
#+----+----+---------+---------+
#| col|2col|third col|      new|
#+----+----+---------+---------+
#|   1|   a|        0|third col|
#|   2|   b|     null|      col|
#|null|   c|        3|third col|
#+----+----+---------+---------+
```

Oops, that's not what I meant. Spark thought I wanted the literal strings `"col"` and `"third col"`. Instead, what I should have written is:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.withColumn(
    'new', 
    when(df['2col'].isin(['a', 'c']), col('third col')).otherwise(col('col'))
).show()
#+----+----+---------+---+
#| col|2col|third col|new|
#+----+----+---------+---+
#|   1|   a|        0|  0|
#|   2|   b|     null|  2|
#|null|   c|        3|  3|
#+----+----+---------+---+
```

Because is col() creates the column expression without checking there's two interesting side effects of this.

1. It can be re-used as it's not df specific
2. It can be used before the df is assigned

```py
age = col('dob') / 365
if_expr = when(age < 18, 'underage').otherwise('adult')

df1 = df.read.csv(path).withColumn('age_category', if_expr)

df2 = df.read.parquet(path)\
    .select('*', age.alias('age'), if_expr.alias('age_category'))
```

`age` generates `Column<b'(dob / 365)'>` 
`if_expr` generates `Column<b'CASE WHEN ((dob / 365) < 18) THEN underage ELSE adult END'>`

Comment: @Dee feel free to edit the answer or post a new one to address the point about `col` being used outside of a Dataframe.

Comment: @Dee it's unlikely. You can check by looking at the execution plan. They should be identical.

Comment: Why is the column name sometimes enough (without col()), e.g. `df.select('column')` or `df.groupby('column1').sum('column2')`?

Comment: @00sc in cases where it's unambiguous, you can do what you're saying