# join parameterization in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I need to parameterized join condition and joining columns should get passes from CLI (I'm using: prompt.in pyspark)

my code is:

```
x1 = col(argv[1])
x2 = col(argv[2])

df = df1.join(df2, (df1.x1 == df2.x2))
```

This is my script:

```
join.py empid emdid
```

I get this error

> df has no such columns.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105363/pyspark-dataframe-column-reference-df-col-vs-dfcol-vs-f-colcol/55106477#55106477) explains why your syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this approach, It will work even if your dataframes are joining on column having same name.

```
argv = ['join.py', 'empid', 'empid']

x1 = argv[1]
x2 = argv[2]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "A"),(2, "B")], ("empid", "c2"))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "A"),(2, "B")], ("empid", "c2"))

df = df1.join(df2, df1[x1] == df2[x2])

df.show()
```