# How to join in pyspark dataframe with dynamic keys

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join, pyspark

I Have two spark DataFrames `captureRate` and `PatientCounts` such as :

PatientCounts:

```python
DataFrame[year_qtr: string, x: double, y: double, z: double]
```

or

```python
DataFrame[year_mon: string, x: double, y: double, z: double]
```

depending on a `timePeriod` variable which could have a value `'year_qtr'` or `'year_mon'`

captureRate :

```python
DataFrame[product1: string, yr_qtr: string, vol: double, capt_rt: double]
```

or

```python
DataFrame[product1: string, yr_mon: string, vol: double, capt_rt: double]
```

Basically the keys are dynamic and different in both cases and I need to join the two dataframes such as :

```python
capturedPatients = (PatientCounts
                      .join(captureRate
                      ,PatientCounts.timePeriod == captureRate.yr_qtr
                      ,"left_outer")
                     )
```

which is giving an error

```python
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'timePeriod'
```

Any pointers how we can join on unequal dynamic keys like this ?

Comment: can you be more specific about *dynamic keys* in this context?

Comment: If the join columns are always in the same positions, you should be able to do a join based on positional columns: `PatientCounts.join(captureRate, on=PatientCounts[0] == captureRate[1], how="left_outer")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the `.` notation like that, but you can use `timePeriod` with the `getItem` (square brackets) operator.

Since the corresponding columns in the `captureRate` DataFrame are slightly different, create a new variable:

```python
# turns "year_mon" into "yr_mon" and "year_qtr" into "yr_qtr"
timePeriodCapture = timePeriod.replace("year", "yr")  

capturedPatients = PatientCounts.join(
    captureRate, 
    on=PatientCounts[timePeriod] == captureRate[timePeriodCapture]
    how="left_outer"
)
```

Alternatively if the join columns are always in the same positions, you can create a join condition by accessing the columns by index:

```python
capturedPatients = PatientCounts.join(
    captureRate, 
    on=PatientCounts[0] == captureRate[1], 
    how="left_outer"
)
```

See more:

- [PySpark DataFrame Column Reference: df.col vs. df['col'] vs. F.col('col')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105363/pyspark-dataframe-column-reference-df-col-vs-dfcol-vs-f-colcol)