# PySpark: How to join dataframes with column names stored in other variables

Tags: python, join, pyspark, left-join, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to learn PySpark. I must left join two dataframes, let's say `A` and `B`, on the basis of the respective columns `colname_a` and `colname_b`. Normally, I would do it like this:

```
# create a new dataframe AB:
AB = A.join(B, A.colname_a == B.colname_b, how = 'left')
```

However, the names of the columns are not directly available for me. They have been stored in a specific module, and I must call them like this:

```
module.COLNAME_A   # contains string with colname of A
module.COLNAME_B   # contains string with colname of B
```

How can I put these string values into the command above, in order to join the dataframes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join in pyspark dataframe with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064511/how-to-join-in-pyspark-dataframe-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use square bracket instead of dot notation to access the column names:

```
AB = A.join(B, A[module.COLNAME_A] == B[module.COLNAME_B], how = 'left')
```

Comment: I see, so the `pandas` syntax works for PySpark as well?

Comment: It's more of a python syntax that works for both `pandas` and PySpark.

Comment: what if I have multiple column? do i need to create key? or is there any other option?