# What is the Spark equivalent to this in Python: VAR_NAME = DF['VAR_NAME']

Tags: pyspark

I want to reference a column without doing `DF['VAR_NAME']` every time, in Python I am able to do this by `VAR_NAME = DF['VAR_NAME']` and referencing that instead.

How do I do this in PySpark?

Comment: you can do `DF.VAR_NAME`, maybe that's little more succinct.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySpark DataFrame Column Reference: df.col vs. df\['col'\] vs. F.col('col')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105363/pyspark-dataframe-column-reference-df-col-vs-dfcol-vs-f-colcol)