# how to select columns in pySpark dataframe from a variable in Python

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pySpark dataframe in python as -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
dataset = sqlContext.range(0, 100).select((col("id") % 3).alias("key"))
```

the column name is key and I would like to select this column using a variable.

```
myvar = "key"
```

now I want to select this column using the `myvar` variable in perhaps a select statement

I tried this

```
dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("dataset")
spark.sql(" select $myvar from dataset ").show
```

but it returns me an error

`no viable alternative at input 'select $'(line 1, pos 8)`

How do I achieve this in pySpark?

Note that I may have different columns in future and I want to pass more than 1 variables or perhaps a `list` into `SELECT` clause.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest you is to collect the data from dataframe and store in ur variable.

Comment: Just use `select`. You can pass in lists also. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55105363/5858851).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dataset.select(myVar)` will select a single column based on variable

`.select` can also take a list `dataset.select([myVar, mySecondVar])`

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is a python list, you can also do this:

```
columns = ['column_a', 'column_b', 'column_c']

#select the list of columns
df_pyspark.select(*columns).show()
```