# Difference between col("col_name") and df.col_name?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am curious if there is any difference between

`df.filter(col('first_name').isin([3, 4, 7]))`

and

`df.filter(df.first_name.isin([3, 4, 7]))`.

Comment: Nope, they have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, appreciate that.

Comment: A more detailed description - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105363/pyspark-dataframe-column-reference-df-col-vs-dfcol-vs-f-colcol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's just a different syntax of referring to [`Column`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column) in Python