# pyspark.sql.functions.col selecting not existing column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I just encurred a strange behavior on pyspark.sql.functions.col.

Filtering and selecting part of dataframe, I had a correct output less column than expected.
I followed the code and I found that I was filtering on a column that was not selected previously, but I had no error selecting it with sql.functions.col method.

I can't understand with PySpark is not raising an exception with pyspark.sql.functions.col on a not existing column. Moreover, it has the correct behaviour as the column was present.

Let me explain it better with an example in python:

```
df = library.spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    ["Id", "Label"]
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

| Id | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo |
| 2 | bar |

```py
df = df.select(F.col("Id"))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

```py
df = df.filter(F.col("Label") == "foo")
df.show(truncate=False)
```

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |

I was wondering on how is it possible that pyspark filters the the df dataframe on a column that is not selected with the previous select.

I just have done some tentative and I found that the issue is caused by pyspark.sql.functions.col since if we do the filter in the following ways, an exception is correctly fired, as I was expected.

```py
df = df.filter(df.Label == "foo")
```

with AttributeError

```py
df = df.filter(df["Label"] == "foo")
```

with AnalysisException

Can someone explain me how is sql.col working in this piece of code?

Comment: lol that's super strange indeed

Comment: I cannot explain well but I think this is something to do with whether you are calling with lazy evaluation or not.  both `df.Label` or `df['Label']` would check whether `Label` is in `df.columns` in `__getattr__` or `__getitem__`.   However, the `F.col` is giving you the expression rather than executing it.  You can try `df.explain()` after `df.select`, then do another `df.explain()` after the `df.filter`.  You can see the DAG plan is modified such that `filter` happens before `select`. As Spark receive the expression rather than executed result, it can alter the planning.

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105363/pyspark-dataframe-column-reference-df-col-vs-dfcol-vs-f-colcol