# Pyspark Usage of Col() Function

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark.I have faced a confusion in which there are multiple ways to access a column of a dataframe. For example:

```
df=select(df.columnname).show()
```

other way:

```
df=select(col("columnname")).show()
```

There are scenarios where we can not use direct column name and we have to use col() thing. However, I am unable to find those scearios where we have to accesss column name using col() otherwise it will throw the error.

Comment: col is not case sensitive

Comment: yes but my question is related to where we should use col("columnname") and where we can direct access column names without using column class??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark DataFrame Column Reference: df.col vs. df\['col'\] vs. F.col('col')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105363/pyspark-dataframe-column-reference-df-col-vs-dfcol-vs-f-colcol)

Answer (score 0):

This would be an example that would fail without using `col()`:

```
df = df.withColumn('col3', when(df.col1 > 2, 5)) \
       .withColumn('col4', when(df.col3 < 6, 4))
```

If you want to access a column that is part of the projection chain, but not of the data frame object yet.

This would work:

```
df = df.withColumn('col3', when(df.col1 > 2, 5)) \
       .withColumn('col4', when(col("col3") < 6, 4))
```